# Como establecer utf-8 en vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Estoy utilizando vue.js para el desarrollo de mi pagina web donde estoy realizando la consulta a la base de datos para obtener algunos datos pero los nombres de los mismos están en formato utf-8 pero el programa no transforma y me muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería muy bueno que nos compartas lo que has avanzado de tu código para ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configura el charset en el arreglo `meta`:

```
metaInfo() {
        return {
            title: 'My',
            titleTemplate: '%s | Titulo',
            meta: [
                { charset: 'utf-8' },
                { equiv: 'Content-Type', content: 'text/html' },
                { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }                 

            ]
        }
    },
```

Comment: Para configurar el charset, lo debo realizar en el App.vue?

Comment: Es mejor así, así lo toma para toda la aplicación.